# InvalidCrossOriginRequest when trying to send a Javascript Asset

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create an "asset controller" shim which will filter static asset requests so only authorized users can get retrieve certain assets.  I wanted to continue to use the asset pipeline so I setup a route like this

```
get 'assets/*assetfile' => 'assets#sendfile'
```

Then I created an AssetsController with one method "sendfile".  Stripping it down to only the stuff that matters, it looks like this:

```
class AssetsController < ApplicationController
  def sendfile
    # Basically the following function forces the file
    # path to be Rails.root/public/assets/basename
    assetfilename=sanitize_filename(params[:assetfile] + '.' + params[:format])

    send_file(assetfilename)
  end
end
```

It looks like I have to run this in production mode as rails by-passes my route for assets in development.  So I precompile my assets and I can verify in the controller that the files exist where they are expected to be.

However, now the problem is that I'm getting a "ActionController::InvalidCrossOriginRequest" when the Javascript asset is requested (just using the default application.* assets for now).  I've read about this error and I understand that as of Rails 4.1 there are special cross-origin protections for Javascript assets.  Sounds good to me, but I don't understand where the "cross-origin" part is coming from.  Using firebug, I can see that the asset requests are being requested from the same domain as the original page.

I am certain that this is the problem because I can solve it by putting "skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token" in the beginning of my controller.  However, I really don't want to do this (I don't fully understand why this check is necessary, but I'm sure there are very good reasons).

The application.html.erb file is unchanged from the default generated file so I assume it's sending the CSRF token when the request is made, just as it would if I didn't have my own controller for assets.

So what am I missing?

Comment: consider storing your protected assets on amazon s3 instead of trying to secure them through rails

Comment: @house9 - Unfortunately, that's not an option in this case (not a technical issue).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think I answered my own question (unsatisfactorily).  Again, long post, so bear with me.  I mistakenly forgot to add this to my original questions, but I'm using Ruby 2.2.0 and Rails 4.2.4.

From looking at the code in "actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb", it looks like Rails is doing two checks.  The first check is the "verify_authenticity_token" method which does the expected validation of the authenticity token for POST requests.  For GET requests, it ALSO sets a flag which causes a second check on the formed computed response to the request.

The check on the response simply says that if the request was NOT an XHR (AJAX) request AND the MIME Type of the response is "text/javascript", then raise an "ActionController::InvalidCrossOriginRequest", which was the error I was getting.

I verified this by setting the type to "application/javascript" for ".js" files in "send_file".  Here's the code:

```
if request.format.js?
   send_file(assetfilename, type: 'application/javascript')
else
   send_file(assetfilename)
end
```

I can skip the response check all together by just adding the following line to the top of my controller class:

```
skip_after_action :verify_same_origin_request
```

The check on the response seems pretty weak to me and it's not clear how this really provides further protection against CSRF.  But I'll post that in another question.

Comment: Did a little more looking at the Rails code and maybe the response check of looking for a Content-Type header value of "text/javascript" is not as weak as I thought.  Rails defines the Javascript mime type to have the content-type of "text/javascript" and it's also synonymous with other javascript content types.  So I guess if you don't specify a content-type yourself when doing a "send_file" or "send_data" then I guess it can potentially protect against a CSRF.  Still kind of weak IMHO, as one could still unwittingly bypass the protection and not implement their own CSRF protection.

Comment: This is interesting and 3 years later still not  quite clear to me. I still cannot see what protection checking a GET for xhr? provides. The discussion here seems relevant: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/21709